# Titan Database: performance issue to iterate over thousands vertices in java code

Tags: java, cassandra, titan

I am using Titan Database (version 1.0.0) with Cassandra backend storage. My database is very big (millions of vertices and edges). I am using elasticsearch for indexing. It does very good job and I'm relatively easily and quickly receives thousands **(~40000)** of vertices as answer of my queries. But i have performance issue then I try to iterate over thous vertices and retrieve basic data saved on vertex properties. It take me about almost 1 min!!!

Usage of parallel streams of Java 8 significantly increase the performance but not enough (10 sec instead of 1 min).

Considered that i have thousand vertices with location property and time stamp. I want to retrieve only vertices with location (Geoshape) within queried area and collect the distinct time stamps.

This is part of my java code using Java 8 parallel streams:

```
TitanTransaction tt = titanWraper.getNewTransaction();
PropertyKey timestampKey = tt.getPropertyKey(TIME_STAMP);
TitanGraphQuery graphQuery = tt.query().has(LOCATION, Geo.WITHIN, cLocation);
Spliterator<TitanVertex> locationsSpl = graphQuery.vertices().spliterator();

Set<String> locationTimestamps = StreamSupport.stream(locationsSpl, true)
        .map(locVertex -> {//map location vertices to timestamp String
            String timestamp = locVertex.valueOrNull(timestampKey);

            //this iteration takes about 10 sec to iterate over 40000 vertices
            return timestamp;
         })
         .distinct()
         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Same code using standard java iteration:

```
TitanTransaction tt = titanWraper.getNewTransaction();
PropertyKey timestampKey = tt.getPropertyKey(TIME_STAMP);
TitanGraphQuery graphQuery = tt.query().has(LOCATION, Geo.WITHIN, cLocation);
Set<String> locationTimestamps = new HashSet<>();
for(TitanVertex locVertex : (Iterable<TitanVertex>) graphQuery.vertices()) {
    String timestamp = locVertex.valueOrNull(timestampKey);
    locationTimestamps.add(timestamp);        
    //this iteration takes about 45 sec to iterate over 40000 vertices            
}
```

This performance is very disappoint me. Even worse if the result will be around 1 million vertices. I try to understand what is the reason of this issue. I am expecting that this should take me less the 1 sec to iterate over thous vertices.

Comment: The performance is tied to resource on machine executing it... If you want to improve the time of process, try to used multi threading to process a batch of vertices (pack of 10000 vertices for example)

Comment: Parallel streams of Java 8 are processed by multi threads.

Comment: Ok! I'm still in Java7! Thanks for the info! So it will be hard to do much better: 10 seconds for 40000 vertices is not so bad: it's not an issue! Maybe you has to review your process to get less vertices! You can set the size of the set with the constructor (int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) you will gain some time not expanding the set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same query but using gremlin traversal instead of graph query has much better performance and much shorter code:

```
TitanTransaction tt = graph.newTransaction();
Set<String> locationTimestamps = tt.traversal().V().has(LOCATION, P.within(cLocation))
    .dedup(TIME_STAMP)
    .values(TIME_STAMP)
    .toSet();
```